# Using the utility for generating TopoJSON maps: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: geospatial, topojson

I want to use [this utility](https://github.com/teslabs/cat-topojson) to generate TopoJSON maps of Catalonia. I performed these steps (as described in the readme of the repository):

```
brew install node
npm install -g topojson   # it gives me Permission error, therefore I run it as sudo
brew install gdal
make
```

After running `make`, I get this error:

```
mkdir -p topo/
topojson \
    -o topo/cat-caps.json \
    --width=500 --height= --margin= \
    --no-pre-quantization \
    --post-quantization= \
    -p tipus=TIPUS_CAP \
    -p cap_prov=ES_CAP_PROV \
    -p municipi=+MUNICIPI \
    -p comarca=+COMARCA \
    -p provincia=+PROVINCIA \
    -- caps=sources/bm/50/20150501//bm50mv33sh1fcm1_20150501_0.shp
make: topojson: Command not found
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'topo/cat-caps.json' failed
make: *** [topo/cat-caps.json] Error 127
```

**UPDATE**

I finally installed `topojson` this way:

```
sudo npm install -g topojson@1

sudo npm install -g topojson
```

But now the command `make` gives me this output:

```
mkdir -p topo/
topojson \
    -o topo/cat-provincies.json \
    --width=500 --height= --margin= \
    --no-pre-quantization \
    --post-quantization= \
    --simplify=2 \
    --id-property=+PROVINCIA \
    -p nom=NOM_PROV \
    -p sup=SUP_PROV \
    -- provincies=sources/bm/50/20150501//bm50mv33sh1fpp1_20150501_0.shp
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'topo/cat-provincies.json' failed
make: *** [topo/cat-provincies.json] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code in the underlying library ran into a segfault and terminated. While I don't know how to debug this particular script, I will note that it doesn't look like it's actively maintained (it was last modified in 2015).

I suggest you peruse [martgnz's recent es-atlas](https://github.com/martgnz/es-atlas) (uploaded literally a couple of days ago) instead. You can extract Catalonia-specific information from the whole-Spain data there.